# JavaScript bind sets the second argument equal to the first one when it should be undefined?

Tags: javascript, reduce, function-composition

I recently tried to understand function composition in javascript. I understood what currying is and how it works, but I saw this code and I can't really understand it. It's function composition using `.reduce(...)`. This is the code:

```
const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f, g) => (...args) => f(g(...args)));

const add5 = x => x + 5;
const add10 = x => x + 10;
const multiply = (x, y) => x * y;

const multiplyAndAdd5 = compose(
  add10,
  add5,
  multiply
);


console.log(multiplyAndAdd5(5, 2));
```

What I don't understand is the reduce function, I tried to break it down into this :

```
const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduce(
  (f, g) => (...args) => {
    console.log("f: ");
    console.log(f);
    console.log("g: ");
    console.log(g);
    for(let i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
      console.log('');
    }
    return f(g(...args))
  },
);
```

In the **console** this shows up:

```
f: 
(...args) => {
    console.log("f: ");
    console.log(f);
    console.log("g: ");
    console.log(g);
    // console.log("args: ");
    // console.log(...args);
    // console.log(f(g(...args…
g: 
(x, y) => x * y

f: 
x => x + 10
g: 
x => x + 5
15 
25
```

What I don't understand is what the *accumulator* actually is in that function and in the first part of the reduce function, **f** is the function itself so, what is *f(g(...args))* in that situation ?

Does anyone know how function composition work in javascript using **.reduce()** ?

Comment: 1. there is no bind here 2. the accumulator is a function. Functional composition gives you a new function that has the effect of all the functions that you composed together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce` can be thought of as putting an operator between each pair of items in a sequence. E.g. reducing `[1, 2, 3]` using `*` would produce `1*2*3` (by performing `((1)*2)*3)`; in the same way, reducing with function composition would reduce `[f, g, h]` into `f∘g∘h` (by performing `((f∘g)∘h)`, also written as `(...args) => f(g(h(...args)))`.

When you don't give an initial value to `reduce`, it takes the first element of the array; so accumulator starts off as `f`. Operating on the element `g`, it returns a new function `(...args) => f(g(...args))` (also known as `f∘g`). In your example, the initial accumulator is `add10`, the element is `add5`, and the result is a function `(...args) => add10(add5(...args))`; let's call it `add10AfterAdd5`.

In the next iteration, the accumulator is `f∘g`, and the element is `h`. The result is a new function `(...args) => (f∘g)(h(...args))`, which is equivalent to `(...args) => f(g(h(...args)))` (also known as `f∘g∘h`). In your example, the accumulator is `add10AfterAdd5`, and the element is `multiply`; the result is `(...args) => add10AfterAdd5(multiply(...args))`, or `(...args) => add10(add5(multiply(...args)))`, or `add10AfterAdd5AfterMultiply`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helped a lot. But what I don't really understand is that, if I have 3 functions, the first function "f" that is taken first is the function itself. I tried to print the functions that the program uses but the first function is the function itself, so it looks like this ```(...args) => {
    console.log("f: ");
    console.log(f);
    console.log("n: ");
    console.log(n);
    return f(n(...args))
  } ```So, the function itself and then 'g' is the first function 'multiply'. So it is f(g(...args)) but f is the function itself. Wouldn't that be recursion ?

Comment: And why is the first function the multiply function ? The first function that I give to ```compose``` is the add function and as you already said, the accumulator is the first element from the given array if it is not given, but multiply is the last one.

Comment: `f` is not "the function itself". You inserted your `console.log` statements into the composition itself (rather than into `reduce`); now a composed function doesn't just invoke the functions, it also has some printing inserted inside. When you execute `multiplyAndAdd5` (which is badly named, I like my `add10AfterAdd5AfterMultiply` much better), it will 1) print `f`, which is in that context `add10AfterAdd5`, and print `g`, which is `multiply`. Your `add10AfterAdd5` contains the `console.log` statements, which is what you are mistaking for the "function itself".

Comment: It will then execute `multiply(5, 2)`, which gives `10`, and then it will execute `add10AfterAdd5(10)`. This, in turn, prints its own `f`, which is `add10`, and its own `g`, which is `add5`, then execute `add5(10)`, giving `15`, and then `add10(15)` giving `25`. The result is then returned up the recursion stack as the final answer.

Comment: I understood the console.log() problem, thank you a lot. But now, what I don't really get is why the ```multiply``` function is the first one taken as a function. As you said, if ```accumulator``` is not given, then the accumulator would be the first function from the array. But the 2 functions from the array are add5 and add10AfterAdd5. ```multiply``` is in fact the last function, so why does it give me an error if I write ```compose(add5, multiply, add10)```, because in that way, multiply would be the first function would be add5 and then multiply. So we would have add5(multiply(...args)) ?

Comment: You get an error, because `multiply` wants two arguments, but every function except the last (innermost) one only gets a single argument (the result of the function inside it); but `compose(add5, multiply, add10)(2, 5)` would build `add5(multiply(add10(2, 5)))` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I understood everything now. Thank you a lot for helping me out